# Replacing value of variable in list of named tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm loading data about phone calls into a list of namedtuples called 'records'. Each phone call has information on the length of the call in the variable 'call_duration'. However, some have the variable set to None. I would like to replace None with zero in all of the records, but the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
for r in records:
        if r.call_duration is None:
            r = r._replace(call_duration=0)
```

How can replace the value in the list? I guess the problem is that the new 'r' isn't stored in the list. What would be the best way to capture in the change in the list?

Comment: post the exact code.

Comment: unrelated but you should use `is None`

Comment: Why don't you just create your own class?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: Because namedtuples are cool. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Well I hope you understand my answer, and why I would suggest a class.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: Sure. You may wish to add a `__slots__ = ()` attribute to it to reduce memory requirements; namedtuples do that, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields): Named tuple instances do not have per-instance dictionaries, so they are lightweight and require no more memory than regular tuples.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I'm not sure what code you want me to post? The records are created by loading the data from .csv-files using several functions, which would only cause distraction. This is the code I've tried to use for cleaning.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thanks. I've changed my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the old record by using its index in the `records` list. You can get that index using `enumerate()`:

```
for i, rec in enumerate(records):
    if rec.call_duration is None:
        records[i] = rec._replace(call_duration=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create your own class, it will benefit you in the future as far as object management goes. When you want to create methods later on for a record, you'll be able to easily do so in a class:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, number = None, length = None):
        self.number = number
        self.length = length

    def replace(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Now you can easily manage your records and replace object attributes as you deem necessary.

```
for r in records:
    if r.length is None:
        r.replace(length = 0)
```